# C++ - Why should I return reference?

Tags: c++, function, reference, return

Why should I return references in C++? I know one reason is that you can use the function on the left hand side of an assignment operator, but what are **all** the most common reasons of returning reference? Also, could you please give some examples of when returning reference should be used.

Edit - I guess a better question is what are the most common reasons of returning reference.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, it's akin to enumerating all uses of pointers. That's just silly. But you could narrow it a bit in a new question and e.g. ask about original rationale. Which was language support for user defined operators. E.g. operator[].

Comment: all the other reasons? I don't think anyone can answer it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you return a reference from a function when you want that function to grant *access to an object* to its caller. This is how containers grant access to their elements with `operator[]`:

```
      value_type& operator[](size_type pos)
const value_type& operator[](size_type pos) const
```

An iterator returns a self-reference from `operator++` in order to support chained operations such as `*++it`; and for that matter it returns a reference from `operator*` in order to grant access into the container over which it’s iterating:

```
value_type& operator*() const {
  return *internal_pointer;
}

iterator& operator++() {
  ++internal_pointer;
  return *this;
}
```